# Abstract class with final uninitialized field

Tags: java, oop

I was wondering if the below code makes any sense, since the compiler warns that "the blank final field objects may not have been initialized". Is there a better way of doing this?

```
public abstract Test {
  protected final ArrayList<Object> objects;
}

public TestSubA extends Test {

  public TestSubA() {
    objects = new ArrayList<Objects>(20);
    // Other stuff
  }
}

public TestSubB extends Test {

  public TestSubB() {
    objects = new ArrayList<Objects>(100);
    // Other stuff
  }
}
```

Comment: +1: for the interest in doing the right thing.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I would make the field final and force the constructors to pass the value up:

```
public abstract class Test {
  private final ArrayList<Object> objects;

  protected ArrayList<Object> getObjects() {
    return objects;
  }

  protected Test(ArrayList<Object> objects) {
    this.objects = objects;
  }
}

public class TestSubA extends Test {

  public TestSubA() {
    super(new ArrayList<Object>(20));
    // Other stuff
  }
}

public class TestSubB extends Test {

  public TestSubB() {
    super(new ArrayList<Object>(100));
    // Other stuff
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Any specific reason why you made it private instead of protected? Say I want to access it directly in the subclasses. And why you use this() instead of super()?

Comment: @lieven: The "this" was a typo - but I prefer fields to be private pretty much everywhere, and shouldn't be part of your exposed API - which includes what derived classes get to see.

Comment: From a bytecode/verifier perspective, `final` means only assigned by the class itself (can be unassigned, assigned multiples times, assigned by a method other than a constructor (not 100% sure about from other instances/static methods)).

Comment: @Tom: That's very interesting. I wish Java allowed multiple assignments within the constructor... this has caused me to write some ugly code to work around it before now.

Comment: *maybe* `getObjects` is redundant? If subclass needs a reference to it, it may introduce a new field and store it. Not sure though.

Comment: Of course, this does not work with anonymus classes and `struct` like classes.

Comment: @DávidHorváth: Well neither of those are abstract classes, as described in the question. It's not clear what scenario you're considering here... you might want to ask a new question.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I took your advice: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36411092/is-there-a-way-to-initialize-final-field-in-anonymus-class

Answer (score 8):

The problem with initializing the final parameters directly in the constructor of the sub-classes is that you need to do it all in one line since super() must be the first statement of the constructor. So instead, I prefer to make the constructor non-public and make a static build method like this:

```
public abstract class Test {
  protected final ArrayList<Object> objects;

  protected Test(ArrayList<Object> objects) {
    this.objects = objects;
  }
}

public class TestSubA extends Test {
  public static TestSubA build() {
    ArrayList<Object> objects = new ArrayList<Object>(20);
    objects.put(...);
    // Other stuff
    return new TestSubA(objects);
  }

  private TestSubA(ArrayList<Object> objects) {
    super(objects);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Instantiate the objects in the abstract class constructor and just pass the difference to the that constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, it might be better to have a constructor in the base class that always sets the field, and not have a default constructor that doesn't set it.  The subclasses can then explicitly pass the parameter in the first line of their constructor using super(value)

Comment: Ooops, sorry. That was a copy/paste error. I've edited my code.